# PHP move A variable to another document

Tags: php, mysql

Hello so I am having a  slight problem at the moment Basically I have a while loop that outputs a table called job from database along with a bid button that links to bid.php. When the button takes me to the page I want it to carry over the jobid of the row that the button was clicked so I can enter the specific value into my database does anyone have any ideas on how to move over currently I am trying to do it using POST but I keep getting errors and the variable dosnt seem to be moving over.I just get a blank page and the id is not displayed.

Here is findjob22.php:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `job` WHERE CONCAT(`job_id`,`location`, `description`, `budget`, `duedate`,`title`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `job`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bid4myjob");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


        <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
        <div class="page-content page-search-result">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Search Form -->
                <form class="form form-horizontal" action="bid.php" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <!--<select id="search-type-select" name="valueToSearch" class="multiselect multiselect-single-lg search-type-select">
                                <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
                                <option value="page">Page</option>
                                <option value="task">Task</option>
                                <option value="user">User</option>
                                <option value="image">Image</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>-->
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="type keyword ..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" name= "submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="icon ion-android-search"></i> Go</button>
                    </span>
                    </div>

                </form>
                <!-- End Search Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Budget</th>
                    <th>Due date</th>
                </tr>

      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                <?php //$jid= $row['job_id']; ?>

                    <td><?php echo $row['job_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['location'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['description'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['duedate'];?></td>
                    <td><form method="post" action="bid.php" class="form-horizontal">
                        <?php //echo _("Enter ") . ' ' . $last_bid_plus . ' ' . _('or more'); ?>

                        <!--<div class="input-group ">

                        <input type="number" value="bid" class="form-control" name="bid" id= "bid" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>-->
                        <input type="submit" name="job_id"   value="<?php $row['job_id']; ?>"
                               class="btn btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary">bid</input>
                        <br/>
                    </form></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->


</body>

</html>
```

Here is bid.php where I am trying to get the specific id of the row from findjob22.php:

```
<?php
// include "job.php" 
$jobid    = $_POST['job_id'];
echo "$jobid"
 ?>
<!--<html>
<div class="col-xs-8">

<div class="page-header white-content">
    <h1><?= _('Your Bid') ?>.</h1>
</div>

<div class="white-content">
    <div class="well">

            <br/><br/>
            <form method="post" action="/listings/bid/<?//=$listingID; ?>/confirm" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?=//$bid_amount?>" class="input-medium" name="bid_amount"/>
                <input type="submit" name="sb_bid" value="<?php// echo _('I agree and I confirm my BID'); ?>" class="btn btn-medium btn-green" />
            </form>

    </div>

</div>

</div>

</html>-->
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? You can use the $_SESSION variable and you can use it on any page you like

Comment: It is just a blank page no error

Comment: "It is just a blank page no error " -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: i believe you need to change `<?php $row['job_id']; ?>` into `<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>`

Comment: sure it is blank, it is outputting an empty string. where do you expect $_POST['job_id'] to come from? also I would suggest looking at some database basics, you do not need to reconnect for each query, this slows it down pretty much

Comment: that dosnt seem to work

Comment: job_id has the value in the html tags?

Comment: Please can you remove the parts of code that are not relevant to this issue?

Comment: why would the variable be empty? it should be job_id?

Comment: I don't believe you can pass a variable in the submit button, use a hidden input like I do below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can pass values in the submit button, but you can use a hidden input to pass the value.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>" name="job_id" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary">bid</input>
```

If you want it to work like you have it use a button.

```
<button type="submit" 
        name="job_id" 
        value="<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>"
        class="btn btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary">
    bid
</button>
```

if you want to also pass some data:

```
<form method="post" 
      action="bid.php" 
      class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text"  
               class="form-control" 
               name="bid" 
               id="bid" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" 
            name="job_id" 
            value="<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>"
            class="btn btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary">
        bid
    </button>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Then you will have a `$_POST["job_id"]` and `$_POST["bid"]` in bid.php

Comment: ah this works thankyou any idea how to have it so that the button shows says bid instead of displaying the value?

Comment: You are using the input type submit, if you want to pass a variable in the button, use a button, not the imput type submit https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp, this will also allow you to name the button that way...

Comment: ah ok i see, is it also possible if i add a text field next to the button that the user could enter a bid and also have that pass through into bid.php aswell as the jobid?

Comment: Thnakyou very helpful